# How to write specific data from JMeter execution output to CSV / Notepad using beanshell scripting

Tags: jmeter-4.0

We are working on web services automation project using JMeter 4.0 In our response, JMeter returns data in json format but we would like to store only specific data (Account ID, Customer ID or Account inquiry fields) from that json into csv file but it stores data in csv file in unformatted format. 
Looking for a workaround on this.

We are using following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

Result = "FAIL";
Responce = prev.getResponseDataAsString():

if(Responce.contains("data"))
    Result = "PASS";

f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Amar.pawar/Desktop/testoup.csv",true);
p = new PrintStream(f);

p.println(vars.get("/ds1odmc") + "," + Result):

p.close();
f.close():
```

Following error is getting encountered:

```
Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  Result = "FA . . . '' Encountered ":" at line 5, column 42.
```

We are looking for saving specific data in CSV (or txt) instead of complete output in unformatted format. Please look into the matter & suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. You use `:` instead of `;` in three lines:

```
Responce = prev.getResponseDataAsString():
...
p.println(vars.get("/ds1odmc") + "," + Result):
...
f.close():
```

And if problem does not solved it may be useful to check the article about [testing complex logic with JMeter beanshell](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Code still not working even after changing colon (:) to semi colon (;). Seems like java import issue, as error prompts...